# How to push Json data to line chart function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I creating a line chart using the High chart, getting value from database and need to pass those values line chart like below

```
//categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun'] // This is static values
categories: [series]  //Passing value from database
```

Now i have created ajax function to pass values

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/api/ReportAPI/GetMonthlyEmployeeFte",
                data: '{}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (Result) {
                    var data = [];
                    for (var i in Result) {
                    var serie = new Array(Result[i].MONTH);
                    data.push(serie));
                      }
                DreawLineChart(data);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
```

Chart code/function

```
function DreawLineChart(series) {
    Highcharts.chart('container2', {
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Employee FTE'
        },
        subtitle: {
            //text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: {
            //categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            categories: [series]  //Here i want push data month from ajax
        },     
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'FTE'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                enableMouseTracking: false
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Singapore',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.4, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]

        }, {
            name: 'New Zealand',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
    });
}
```

But its showing data in chart at one point instead of showing Jan  March Nov Dec separately.

[image: line chart]

Comment: Can you share the value of series that you are passing to the function ?

Comment: I think `series` is array so use it directly like `categories: series` check buggy demo to understand https://jsfiddle.net/pmm5gqqb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use square brackets for `series`. `series` is an array already. Use only `categories: series`

Comment: how do i pass second parameter any idea?var serie = new Array(Result[i].MONTH);
                        data.push(serie);
                        //var _line_chart = new Array(Result[i].YEAR);
                         var fte = new Array(Result[i].MONTHLY_TOTAL_FTE);
                        //var fte =[1,2,3,4]
                       data2.push(fte);
                       // alert(serie);
                      //data.push(serie);
                    } 
                    DreawLineChart(data,data2);